# Getting rid of exponents with n when solving with annihilators: $a_n=a_{n-1}+2a_{n-2}+2^n+n^2$

Tags: recurrence-relations, computer-science, recursion

To solve the following with annihilators:

$a_n=a_{n-1}+2a_{n-2}+2^n+n^2$, for $n\ge2$, with initial conditions $a_1=0$ and $a_0=0$

we would have to get rid of the $2^n$ term at least, otherwise any E<> operation will just reduce the exponent. If we try to get the $2^n$ term to cancel out somehow by picking a convenient substitute, then the $n^2$ term becomes problematic. Dividing through makes the equation too complicated for annihilators.

Comment: Do you have to use annihilators?  Would another method of solving be sufficient?

Comment: @DanielV The book this is from says there is an answer using annihilators. I'm not sure if they mean annihilators only, or in combination with other methods. I'm try to figure it how (if it's possible) to do it with annihilators only.

Answer (score 2):

First let $a_n = b_n + xn^2 + yn +z$. Compute $x,y,z$ such that we have
$$b_n = b_{n-1} + 2b_{n-2} + 2^n$$
Now set $c_n = b_n/2^n$, we then have
$$c_n = \dfrac{c_{n-1}}2 + \dfrac{c_{n-2}}2 + 1$$
Now you should be able to take it from here.

Comment: What happened to $n^2$? This solution does most of the legwork with characteristic equations, though I guess I could use annihilators at this point.

Comment: @Whitesizzle Your $x,y,z$ are so chosen to absorb the quadratic terms in it.

Comment: So we chose to set $z=0$? Not sure how we did that.

Comment: @Whitesizzle Why don't you plug in $a_n = b_n+xn^2+yn+z$ in the recurrence you have first and simplify? Match the coefficients of $n^2$, $n$ and the constant term to solve for $x$, $y$ and $z$.